# How to translate Aurora Mysql ddl to Redshift ddl

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-aurora

What would be the best way to list a serie of Auora Mysql ddl objects and translate them to Redshift ddl (data type mapping, PK, encoding)?

Im trying to migrate from Aurora Mysql to Redshift with lambdas, but I need to create target tables first. This operation has to be done before every load, so it needs to be automated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the [Database Migration Service](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/)

You can use DMS for the following DDL operations, further actions would need to be performed by the [Schema Conversion Tool](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/schema-conversion-tool/?nc=sn&loc=2):

- Create table
- Drop table
- Rename table
- Add column
- Drop column
- Rename column
- Change column data type

When you use this service it would need to boot up a resource in your account to perform the operation, so be aware of this as it will have a [cost](https://aws.amazon.com/dms/pricing/) to it.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I tried DMS and it works fine, but I having trouble when I want to schedule tasks to run periodically (I can't call them via CW Events directly) and how to let know other services that a task has finished correctly, since DMS events are not differentiated that way and I can't filter them with a filter policy (Im planning to use a lambda function to pre filter them). Overall seems a bit clumsy.. for such an 'easy task, that is why I was hoping there was another solution...

Comment: Yeah unfortunately you would need to have your trigger as a Lambda function which triggers this task. Regarding notifying when stopped CloudWatch events do support DMS but you must have the specific event name used from CloudTrail. Other than this it would be your own/third party solution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with liquibase (or flyway) and jenkins for scheduling as seen in the [aws blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/opensource/rds-code-change-deployment/).

1. Liquibase's [generateChangeLog](https://docs.liquibase.com/commands/community/generatechangelog.html) can create a changelog representing the schema of your mysql db
2. With the generated Changelog you can [update](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/updating-the-database.html) the Redshift schema with the latest schema changes from your source